# Why the code is printing 0 at first

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int t, z;
  scanf("%d", &t);

  while (t--) {
    string buf, str;
    getline(cin, str);
    stringstream ss(str);
    int cnt = 0;

    set<string> tokens;

    while (ss >> buf) {
        tokens.insert(buf);
    }

    for (set<string>::iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it) {
        cnt++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", cnt);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

This code is just used for counting the number of different words present in a string. e.g for input

> i am i

wil give output

> 2

But when i enter the test cases it first gives 0 as output neglecting the last test case..what is the reason for it?? and how can it be corrected??
Here is the [link](http://ideone.com/DADEvk)

Comment: Most probably `scanf()`, yet again. Don't use it. Forget it. Use `std::getline()` and `std::stoi()` for getting an integer from the standard input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your scanf is only reading the integer - it doesn't read the end of line.  So your first "line" is the rest of the line with "4" on it.  Either read to the end of the line or use the solution from user3477950.

Answer (score 3):

Sameer,

modify your code thus:

```
    int main()
    {
        char eatNewline = '\0';
        int t, z;
        scanf("%d", &t);
        eatNewline=getchar();   //Eat the enter key press.


        while (t--)
        {
          string buf, str;
          getline(cin, str);
          stringstream ss(str);
          int cnt = 0;

          set<string> tokens;

          while (ss >> buf)
          {
            tokens.insert(buf);
          }

          for (set<string>::iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it)
          {
            cnt++;
          }

          printf("%d\n", cnt);
        }

 return 0;
```

}

```
[root@saas ~]# ./tst
4
now do it now
3
now     do it now
3
I am  good boy
4
am am
1
```

Please let me know if that helps you! :)

Answer (score 1):

because after you `scanf("%d", &t)`, the tailing `\n` is still in the input string buffer.

To fix this problem, you can change it to:

```
scanf("%d ", &t); // add a space after %d to catch the '\n' character
```

or add

```
cin >> ws;
```

or use `gets(...)` etc.

Comment: notice that the ws is not a user defined variable but std::ws, to skip all the blank characters until a non-blank character is next.